# jquery swap images on click and hide then

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a menu. OVer a canvas I load different images and position them using CSS. Currently I operate with SHOW / HIDE with a lots of code duplication. My questions are:
- instead of just hidding an image, how can I change it on click with another one? and then again hide it, if I should click another button?
- is it possible to write all this code somehow simpler?

Thanks a lot...

```
   $("#ten").click(sizeTen);
function sizeTen(){
    cb_ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    clickSound();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#twenty").show();
    $("#forty").show();
    $("#sixty").show();
}

$("#twenty").click(sizeTwenty);
function sizeTwenty(){
    cb_ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    clickSound();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#tenClick").show();
    $("#ten").show();
    $("#forty").show();
    $("#sixty").show();
}

$("#forty").click(sizeForty);
function sizeForty(){
    cb_ctx.lineWidth = 40;
    clickSound();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#ten").show();
    $("#twenty").show();
    $("#sixty").show();
}

$("#sixty").click(sizeSixty);
function sizeSixty(){
    cb_ctx.lineWidth = 60;
    clickSound();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#ten").show();
    $("#twenty").show();
    $("#forty").show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this could probably be a lot simpler, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve. Can you post an example or a jsFiddle?

Comment: i'm working a small drawing program, so I can learn with it. the complete thing is visible at http://www.oxylus.si/srecno/draw. I would like to swap those buttons (colors and size) with some other images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be You Could shrink your coding by the following piece of code,

```
$("#ten,#twenty,#sixty").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put all numeric values along with the corresponding IDs in a map and create a single handler for all buttons:

```
var boo = function () {
    var values = { 'ten': 10, 'twenty': 20, 'forty': 40, 'sixty': 60 };
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).hide();

//    cb_ctx.lineWidth = values[id];
//    clickSound();

    $.each(values, function(key, value) {
        if (id != key) {
            $('#' + key).show();
        }
    });
};

$('#ten, #twenty, #forty, #sixty').click(boo);
```

Check out a jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/LNFza/4/

Cheers.